# How To Specific Replace in MsSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I have a problem.

I want to replace all columns which start with 2,finish with 2 and contain 2 inside.
For example for my column;

> [Numbers]
>
> 1, 2, 22, 33, 4, 5
>
> 2, 3, 42, 25, 6
>
> 12, 28, 62, 2

I want to replace "only 2" (not 22 or 25 etc.) with X. Here is my query:

```
UPDATE mytable
set Numbers = replace(Numbers, ',2', ',X') WHERE Numbers like '%,2'

UPDATE mytable
    set Numbers = replace(Numbers, ',2,', ',X,') WHERE Numbers like '%,2,%'

UPDATE mytable
    set Numbers = replace(Numbers, '2,', 'X,') WHERE Numbers like '2,%'
```

But output is not true. This code replace all 2 in the column with X.

Can anyone help me? How can I write true query?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and normalize your database. Read [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) where the accepted answer explains in details why it's that bad.

Comment: I can't. I didn't create this database and I need just modify like I said for now.

Comment: What would be your expected output based on your given data

Comment: For example at second row; I need get this [X, 3, 42, 25, 6]  instead of [2, 3, 42, 25, 6] but the output is [X, 3, 4X, 25, 6]

Comment: For the input [1, 2, 22, 33, 4, 5] the output should be [1, X, 22, 33, 4, 5]?

Comment: Yes, There is a problem in collumns which start with 2 and finish with 2. I edited my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this then remove `','` (first and end)

```
SELECT REPLACE(',' + REPLACE('1, 2, 22, 33, 4, 5', ' ', '') + ',', ',2,', ',X,') -- ,1,X,22,33,4,5,
SELECT REPLACE(',' + REPLACE('2, 3, 42, 25, 6', ' ', '') + ',', ',2,', ',X,') -- ,X,3,42,25,6,
SELECT REPLACE(',' + REPLACE('12, 28, 62, 2', ' ', '') + ',', ',2,', ',X,') -- ,12,28,62,X,
```

Query looks like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Numbers = SUBSTRING(NewNumbers, 2, LEN(NewNumbers) - 2)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
       Id, 
       REPLACE(',' + REPLACE(Numbers, ' ', '') + ',', ',2,', ',X,')  AS NewNumbers
    FROM
        mytable
) A
WHERE
    mytable.Id = A.Id
    -- Your where clause
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just an idea...

```
UPDATE mytable
set Numbers = 'X,'+substring(Numbers,3) WHERE Numbers like '2,%'

UPDATE mytable
    set Numbers = replace(Numbers, ',2,', ',X,') WHERE Numbers like '%,2,%'

UPDATE mytable
    set Numbers = substring(Numbers,1,LENGTH(Numbers)-2)+',X' WHERE Numbers like '%,2'
```